# merging images to create video using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am creating a video from images using ffmpeg. I am using a file that contains the list of images as

```
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\nature3.jpg'
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\img_001.jpg'
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\img_003.jpg'
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\img_006.jpg'
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\nature3.jpg'
file 'C:\wamp64\www\test\public\userFolder\media\nature4.jpg'
```

I am using the following command to create video

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -r 1/10 -f concat -safe 0 -i "imagepaths.txt" -c:v libx264  -s 920x640 "Jawedout.mp4"
```

The video is being created but the start of video is blank. The video show dark black screen for few secs then show the first image mentioned in file.

However, if the change the command to

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "imagepaths.txt" -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" -s 920x640 "Jawedout.mp4"
```

Then in video I am not seeing first image and last image.